# display tables even if one is empty

Tags: sql

Im trying to get a query display table rows, even if one table is empty.

For now i need to have values in every table to get an output.

```
 SELECT * FROM blog JOIN user JOIN photos WHERE blog.user_id = user.id 
 AND blog.id = photos.blog_id
```

I tried with an OR IN like this

```
SELECT * FROM blog JOIN user JOIN photos 
WHERE blog.user_id = user.id OR blog.id 
IN (SELECT photos.blog_id FROM photos WHERE blog.id = photos.blog_id
```

But that didn't do the trick. any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simpliest answer is to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   blog LEFT JOIN user ON blog.user_id = user.id
       LEFT JOIN photos ON blog.id = photos.blog_id
```

this will display all records from table `blog` even if table `photos` is empty.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you use proper join syntax, then this is easy:

```
SELECT *
FROM blog left outer JOIN
     user
     On blog.user_id = user.id left outer join
     photos
     on blog.id = photos.blog_id
```